# WordPress - Menu item disappear when save menu

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am using the latest WordPress version (5.2).
- I replaced old version wp files with the latest(wp-admin, wp-includes, root files).
- No plugin activate.
- Using the Default Theme.
The issue is when I add pages or anything in the menu and then save the menu, randomly menu item disappear, re-order the child menu and delete parent menu. 
Before Saving menu - http://prntscr.com/npngof
After saving menu - http://prntscr.com/npngx4

I have set max_input_vars 1000 but still not working.
It seems like an issue should be in the database. It's just my assumption

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: do you have cache plugin installed? did you try switching the theme? try disabling one plugin at a time and save menu. It might be plugin conflicts or theme problem

Comment: I have already mentioned that we have deactivated all the plugins so there is no chance of caching issue even I am using the latest and fresh  WordPress files.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the browser's devtool console when saving or editing the menu?

Comment: Not any javascript errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can call that page using custom link else you have to call it by Primary Menu

Comment: There is issue with database so i have set all tables in primary key and auto increment so now it's working Thanks.